# Is it ok to use one of either?

Tags: word-order

Is it ok to use "one of either"? The reason I am asking is because it always seems like there are always some subjects before the word "either" in that case like this:

> You may use one of either (knife or scissor for cutting paper).

So I want to know if deleting the parenthesized part, "knife or scissor for cutting paper", would be fine so that it will look like this:

> You may use one of either.

Thank you.

Comment: The reason it's usually 'You may use one of either X or Y [ ... ]' is that 'either' needs two (or possibly more) referents. They may have been mentioned before: 'There are spokeshaves and drawknives available on my bench; you may use one of either' – but it's more usual to use 'either' as a determiner after 'one of'.

Comment: So when there is going to be no determiner after word "either", it is impossible to use just "one of either"  or is it just not recommended?

Comment: _Either_ **is** a determiner when followed by NP + _or_  + NP.

Comment: there needs to be subjects, like @EdwinAshworth said

Comment: It's confusing to use the word 'subjects' rather than 'referents' here, and confusing to say 'it always seems like there are always some subjects **before** the word "either" in that case like this:

You may use one of either (knife or scissor for cutting paper).'.

Comment: That is true. Word subject confuses things here.

Answer (score 1):

**Examples**

**1.** You will be offered charcoal or crayon.  You may use *either one*./You may *use either*.

**2.** You will be offered a sketch pad or a sketch block, and charcoal or crayon.  You may *use one of eithe*r.

**3.** You will be offered pad or block, charcoal or conté, easel or table. You may use *one of each*.

Notice, the subjects are stated in a previous sentence

Comment: @Mari-Lou A, nice edit, Explanation of "one of either." This is only used when you are offered two choices; e.g. a choice of socks in red or blue, in wool or nylon; choose one of either; a choice of books from fact or fiction, best-seller or esoteric, choose one of either.

Answer (score 0):

It is awkward, a little too wordy, but there is nothing wrong with it. It would just be a style choice. :)

Comment: By wordy, do you refer to "you may use one of either knife or scissor for cutting paper", or the shorter one "you may use one of either"?

Comment: Because you might have misunderstood me since I wrote my question so vaguely. That's why I edited it, even though from you saying "it would just be a style choice" I can kind of assume you got what I tried to ask.

Comment: you can drop " **one of** " but you need the tools to be mentioned